# Setting Finder label via AppleScript on High Sierra

Tags: macos, applescript, finder, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to use AppleScript to set the label of a file to a specific colour; or rather, I already have a script that used to work, but ever since upgrading to High Sierra it no longer does.

I've stripped it down to the absolute basics (always sets label to green):

```
on run theArguments
    set theFile to POSIX file (item 1 of theArguments)
    tell application "Finder" to set (theFile's label index) to 6
end run
```

If you save this to a file (`green.scpt`) then you can run it from Terminal with the following command:

```
osascript ~/Downloads/green.scpt ~/Downloads/green.scpt
```

(substitute the paths for wherever you store the script)

This *should* turn the script's label in the Finder to green, but doesn't (at least on High Sierra), instead giving the following error message:

```
/Users/haravikk/Downloads/green.scpt: execution error: Finder got an error: Can’t set label index of file "Users:haravikk:Downloads:green.scpt" to 6. (-10006)
```

Am I doing something wrong here? If not, and this is a bug, then is there some other way to change a file's label via script?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use tell application  before change label index

```
on run theArguments
tell application "Finder"
    set thisItem to POSIX file theArguments as alias
    if label index of thisItem is not 6 then
        set the label index of thisItem to 6
    end if
end tell
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (added "as alias"):

```
on run theArguments
    set theFile to POSIX file (item 1 of theArguments) as alias
    tell application "Finder" to set (theFile's label index) to 6
end run
```

Note though that labels are long gone, and have been replaced with tags.

Comment: I should have noted that I actually tried an alias, but all that does in my case is change the error to:
`Can’t set alias "Users:haravikk:Downloads:green.scpt" to 6. (-10006)`. Are you running on an APFS system volume at all? I am, so maybe that's the cause of the issue?

Comment: Yes, it's on APFS and I get that exact same error only when I remove the "as alias" again.

Comment: Well that's frustrating; I get basically the same error no matter whether I'm using an alias or not. Definitely seems like a bug of some kind then, but I'm not sure if that leaves me any options for a workaround?